# Ajax making 2 calls to Api

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call that will delete a record when I click the delete button, the problem i'm having is that i am making 2 calls to the db.

I do not know where.

one is a Get and one is a Delete

```
    function deleteRegion(id) {
        let url = baseUrl + "regions/" + id;
        let sucess = getSuccess(id);
        deleteItem(url, id, sucess);
}

function getSuccess(id) {
    return function () {
        $("#" + id)
            .addClass("animated bounceOutUp");
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#" + id)
                .remove();
        },
            600);
    }
}

function deleteItem(url, id, success) {
    let data = { id: id };
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: success,
        error: function() {
            alert("There was an error deleting");
        }
    });
}

    <tbody>
        @if ( Model.Any() )
        {
            foreach ( var region in @Model )
            {
                <tr id="@region.Id">
                    <td><span class="fa fa-pencil-square"></span></td>
                    <td>@region.State.Name</td>
                    <td>@region.Name</td>
                    <td><a class="fa fa-trash-o" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@region.Id" onclick='deleteRegion("@region.Id")' ></a></td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
```

[image]

can anyone tell me where and/ or tell me how to find it.

Comment: Are you able to click on the request to get more information about it in the Dev Tools? If you click the name, you should be able to see the url where the request is being made to get a better picture of where it may be coming from

Comment: I cannot find the calling url

Comment: The only other idea I can think with the code provided is that you are using an anchor tag, `<a>`, for your button which may be triggering an event, you could try something like:
`onclick='deleteRegion(event, "@region.Id")'` and call `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: thank you I found this error. it was that I was calling asp-action="Delete" instead of just calling the api only